# Beginner Question on using fOptions: GBSVolatility

Tags: r

So sorry to trouble you guys, I am pretty new in Programming so it is really hard for me to understand most posted solutions online. I tried searching for the answers to my problem but seem to be unable to find any.

I have a dataframe of option details. It is called gcp5.

```
> str(gcp5)
Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame':   90 obs. of  10 variables:
 $ Expiry Date  : POSIXct, format: "2019-12-20" "2019-12-20" ...
 $ Strike       : num  1210 1215 1220 1225 1230 ...
 $ Open Interest: num  34 87 50 52 115 17 99 62 907 36 ...
 $ Underlying   : num  1209 1209 1209 1209 1209 ...
 $ CallOrPut    : chr  "c" "c" "c" "c" ...
 $ Bid          : num  43.2 44.1 41.9 40 34.8 36.1 31.4 29.6 27.9 28.4 ...
 $ Ask          : num  44.1 44.7 42.7 40.6 35.7 36.7 32.2 30.4 28.6 29 ...
 $ value        : num  1484 3863 2115 2096 4054 ...
 $ time         : num  0.205 0.205 0.205 0.205 0.205 ...
 $ price        : num  43.7 44.4 42.3 40.3 35.2 ...
```

I want to add a new column called vol. I want to use the function GBSVolatility (under library fOptions) to populate this new column. I used the command as per below and got some wierd error messages. I am unsure what is wrong.

```
gcp6 <- mutate(gcp5, vol = GBSVolatility(gcp5$price, gcp5$CallOrPut, 
                                          gcp5$Underlying, gcp5$Strike, gcp5$time, 0.03, 0))

#Error in uniroot(.fGBSVolatility, interval = c(-10, 10), price = price,  : 
#f() values at end points not of opposite sign
#In addition: Warning messages:
# 1: In if (is.na(f.lower)) stop("f.lower = f(lower) is NA") :
# the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
#2: In if (is.na(f.upper)) stop("f.upper = f(upper) is NA") :
#  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

I understand that everyone has their own responsibilities in life and need time to fulfil them. Thank you everyone who spent time trying to help answer my query. Really appreciate your kindness in helping.

In addition (details on the first and last 5 data rows):

```
> dput(head(gcp5))                                          
structure(list(`Expiry Date` = structure(c(1576800000, 1576800000, 
1576800000, 1576800000, 1576800000, 1576800000), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), Strike = c(1210, 1215, 1220, 1225, 
1230, 1235), `Open Interest` = c(34, 87, 50, 52, 115, 17), Underlying = c(1209, 
1209, 1209, 1209, 1209, 1209), CallOrPut = c("c", "c", "c", "c", 
"c", "c"), Bid = c(43.2, 44.1, 41.9, 40, 34.8, 36.1), Ask = c(44.1, 
44.7, 42.7, 40.6, 35.7, 36.7), value = c(1484.1, 3862.8, 2115, 
2095.6, 4053.75, 618.8), time = c(0.205479452054795, 0.205479452054795, 
0.205479452054795, 0.205479452054795, 0.205479452054795, 0.205479452054795
), price = c(43.65, 44.4, 42.3, 40.3, 35.25, 36.4)), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

> dput(tail(gcp5))                                          
structure(list(`Expiry Date` = structure(c(1576800000, 1576800000, 
1576800000, 1576800000, 1576800000, 1576800000), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), Strike = c(1180, 1185, 1190, 1195, 
1200, 1205), `Open Interest` = c(48, 12, 119, 9, 0, 26), Underlying = c(1209, 
1209, 1209, 1209, 1209, 1209), CallOrPut = c("p", "p", "p", "p", 
"p", "p"), Bid = c(47.9, 59.4, 52.7, 64.3, 72, 69.4), Ask = c(52.4, 
60.1, 56.3, 65.2, 73.5, 70.2), value = c(2407.2, 717, 6485.5, 
582.75, 0, 1814.8), time = c(0.205479452054795, 0.205479452054795, 
0.205479452054795, 0.205479452054795, 0.205479452054795, 0.205479452054795
), price = c(50.15, 59.75, 54.5, 64.75, 72.75, 69.8)), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Comment: Can you run `GBSVolatility` for any sample example ?

Comment: Nope, I cant. I tried gcp55 <- head (gcp5, 3). Then I ran the same function and still same error. gcp6 <- mutate(gcp55, vol = GBSVolatility(gcp55$price, gcp55$CallOrPut, gcp55$Underlying, gcp55$Strike,
                                         gcp55$time, 0.03, 0))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is `GBSVolatility` expects to calculate volatility for one option price at a time but in the attempt we are passing the complete column to the function which it is unable to process. There are multiple ways to deal with this.

One of it is use `rowwise` which will automatically pass arguments in a row-wise manner

```
library(dplyr)
library(fOptions)
library(purrr)

gcp5 %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(vol = GBSVolatility(price, CallOrPut, Underlying, Strike, time, 0.03, 0))
```

However, row-wise is a bit outdated, we can also use `pmap_dbl` from `purrr`

```
gcp5 %>%
   mutate(vol = pmap_dbl(list(price, CallOrPut, Underlying, Strike, time), 
                 GBSVolatility, r = 0.03, b = 0))
```

Or in base R, use `mapply`

```
with(gcp5,mapply(GBSVolatility, price, CallOrPut, Underlying, Strike,time, 0.03, 0))
#[1] 0.2031476937 0.2173287575 0.2180045839 0.2187683891 0.2050072991 0.2196630834
```

Answer (score 1):

I used another method to get what I want. But I would still like to know why is my original method wrong and how to use my original method instead of my new method. Thank you all.

New method is as per below but is not my preferred method, because the naming conventions is so much more complicated.

```
vol <- function(x) GBSVolatility(as.numeric(x["price"]), as.character(x["CallOrPut"]), as.numeric(x["Underlying"]),    
                                 as.numeric(x["Strike"]), as.numeric(x["time"]), r = 0.03, b = 0.00)
gcp6 <- mutate(gcp5, vol = apply(gcp5, 1, vol))
```